# How can i make database connection open in JDBCTemplate spring 4

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jdbctemplate

I am using JDBCTemplate in spring4 for executing select query which returns a Blob object. Now i am trying to convert Blob object into string using following code

```
Blob image;  
ImageScanningBean imageScanningBean = new ImageScanningBean();  
image = rs.getBlob("IMAGEOUT");  
StringBuffer strOut = new StringBuffer();  
try
{  
    String aux;  
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(image.getBinaryStream()));  
   while ((aux=br.readLine())!=null) 
   {  
        strOut.append(aux);
   }  
   strOut.toString();  
   imageScanningBean.setImageOutBase64(strOut.toString());  
}  
 catch(Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But i am getting error at following line as Connection Closed

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(image.getBinaryStream()));
```

How can i make database connection open in JDBCTemplate

Comment: How do you invoke the method? Looks like you read the blob in a method annotated with `@Transactional` and pass to process. So it could be connection is closed after exit the annotated read() method.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, i have resolved the problem. Before i were used the following code                                                                                  bean = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(query, new Object[]{tokenId,tellerId},new BeanPropertyRowMapper<TokenDetailsBean>(TokenDetailsBean.class));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before i have used queryForObject() which automatically closes the connection when operation is done 
    bean = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select * from tablename", new Object[]{tokenId,tellerId},new BeanPropertyRowMapper(TokenDetailsBean.class));

So to keep connection alive i have just added  mapRow()

```
try
    {
        imageScanningBean = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select * from tablename", new Object[]{imageScanningBean.getTellerId()},new BeanPropertyRowMapper<ImageScanningBean>(){
            public ImageScanningBean mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                Blob image;
                ImageScanningBean imageScanningBean = new ImageScanningBean();
                image = rs.getBlob("IMAGEOUT");
                StringBuffer strOut = new StringBuffer();
                try
                {
                    String aux;
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(image.getBinaryStream()));
                    while ((aux=br.readLine())!=null) 
                    {
                        strOut.append(aux);
                    }
                    strOut.toString();
                    imageScanningBean.setImageOutBase64(strOut.toString());
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return imageScanningBean;
            }
        });
    } 
    catch(EmptyResultDataAccessException er)
    {
        er.printStackTrace();
        return imageScanningBean;
    }
```